# multiple intent extras

Tags: android, android-intent

Passing extras between activities don't work. I tried all approaches I know.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SomethingMore.class);
i.putExtra(intentStart, 1);
i.putExtra(intentSomething, true);
startActivity(i);
```

and

```
Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    start = extras.getInt(intentStart);
    something = extras.getBoolean(intentSomething);
}
```

doesn't work. I also tried it with this methods to retreive

```
start = intent.getIntExtra(intentStart, 0);
something = intent.getBooleanExtra(intentSomething, false);
```

, which don't worked, too. 
Using a `Bundle` doesn't work as well ..

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SomethingMore.class);
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putInt(intentStart, 1);
mBundle.putBoolean(intentSomething, true));
i.putExtras(mBundle);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Can you debug the application and use Eclipse to check if the data is actually in the `Intent` when in the second `Activity`?

Comment: How are you accessing the intent in the started activity? Also, are you **absolutely sure** that the values of `intentStart` and `intentSomething` are the same in the starting activity and the started activity? (It's best to use a `public static final String` field declared somewhere accessible to both activities.)

Comment: @TedHopp `intentStart` and `intentSomething` are `public static final String`s. The intent is accessed with `getIntent();`.

Comment: Click the bug icon in Eclipse, rather than the green arrow thingy

Comment: @RobinKanters I know, but how to grab the intent data?

Comment: There is a variable pane in the Debug perspective you can use. Add a breakpoint in your `onCreate()` and browse the `Intent` that way

Comment: It's in _this->mIntent->mExtras_

Comment: The problem is, my variables window is kinda empty...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21201/discussion-between-leandros-and-robin-kanters)

Comment: **"intentStart and intentSomething are public static final Strings"** Let me guess...they're declared in the first `Activity` correct? If so, don't do that - put them in a helper class that can be accessed by both activities. One `Activity` should never attempt to access static fields in another `Activity`.

Comment: @Squonk Thanks, will refactor the code to use a HelperClass for all my static variables.

Comment: @Squonk - Can you provide a rationale for that rule (_"One `Activity` should never attempt to access static fields in another `Activity`"_)? I've never seen that advice before and violating it (which I do routinely) has never caused an issue for me.

Comment: @TedHopp : **"Can you provide a rationale for that rule"** A number of reasons. The first being I've seen so many questions here on SO where it has actually been the cause of failure or unpredictable results. The main one is the `Activity` life-cycle - perhaps static fields are less of an evil than static methods but basically I try to persuade people against exposing any `public static` fields/methods in an `Activity`. It's simply not how the `Activity` class was designed to be used IMO and I've seen it cause so many problems.

Comment: @Squonk - By definition, static fields (and static methods, for that matter) aren't tied to an instance of an `Activity`, so they can't be affected by the activity lifecycle. (Granted someone can do something bizarre like stashing an instance reference in a static field, but that kind of self-inflicted injury can be done with a field in a helper class as well.) To me, having an activity class publish the keys that it expects as intent extras makes more sense than moving the keys to a third class and thus breaking a semantically important coupling.

Comment: @TedHopp : OK, perhaps I worded my comments badly and I agree that a `static final` key is the lesser of the evils (or not evil at all). The damage I've seen *has* often been caused by `public static` fields which reference instance fields and the use of an instance field from within a `static` method. Perhaps we can agree to disagree (partially at least). Many of my `Intent` keys are used by different `Activity` classes in my current app and it basically makes more sense (to me) to define them by way of a helper class.

Comment: @Squonk In my app I havo to use `public static` fields, because I, for example, update the `ActionBar` from a fragment. Is this bad and shouldn't be done? How is the correct way to do it? With a interface / listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the Intent Extra keys the same? ;) (intentSomething and intentStart)